# como agrupar multiple relaciones con left join laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-8

```
    $product = Product::select('products.id', 'products.description', 'products.name', 'products.image', 'products.price', 'products.stock', 'B.name AS brand', 'products.brands_id', 'products.categories_id', 'products.sub_categories_id', 'products.status', 'C.name AS category', 'S.name AS subcategory', DB::raw('count(product_ratings.stars) AS stars'))
        ->join('brands AS B', 'B.id', 'products.brands_id')
        ->join('categories AS C', 'C.id', 'products.categories_id')
        ->join('sub_categories AS S', 'S.id', 'products.sub_categories_id')
        ->leftJoin('product_ratings', 'product_ratings.product_id', 'products.id')
        ->groupBy('products.id', 'products.description', 'products.name', 'products.image', 'products.price', 'products.stock', 'brand', 'products.brands_id', 'products.categories_id', 'products.sub_categories_id', 'products.status', 'category', 'subcategory', 'stars')
        ->get();
```

lo que intento es que dependiendo de los product_ratings que existan me devuleva el count(),
pero me devuelve los productos duplicados(dependiendo de los leftjoin que encuentra)

Answer (score 0):

No se si entendi bien, pero si necesitas que devuelva el conteo de los product_ratings porque utilizas leftjoin?. LeftJoin hará que cuando no encuentre un dato para dicha relación te devuelva un campo nulo. Creo que deberías user join

Comment: si utilizo join, no me sale el producto si no tiene un 'product_ratings' asociado

Answer (score 0):

```
        $product = Product::select('products.id', 'products.description', 'products.name', 'products.image', 'products.price', 'products.stock', 'B.name AS brand', 'products.brands_id', 'products.categories_id', 'products.sub_categories_id', 'products.status', 'C.name AS category', 'S.name AS subcategory')
        ->join('brands AS B', 'B.id', 'products.brands_id')
        ->join('categories AS C', 'C.id', 'products.categories_id')
        ->join('sub_categories AS S', 'S.id', 'products.sub_categories_id')
        ->addSelect(DB::raw('count(product_ratings.stars) AS stars'))
        ->leftJoin('product_ratings', 'product_ratings.product_id', 'products.id')
        ->groupBy('products.id', 'products.description', 'products.name', 'products.image', 'products.price', 'products.stock', 'brand', 'products.brands_id', 'products.categories_id', 'products.sub_categories_id', 'products.status', 'category', 'subcategory')
        ->get();
```

el error era que inclui en el group by el campo stars,por eso se duplicaba